# online radio with jQuery and the jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer, shoutcast, internet-radio

I followed the instructions as given on this site http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-an-online-radio-using-jquery-and-jplayer and made the radio as stated in the link but i have a question that i want to do shoutcast streaming with the help of http://www.listen2myradio.com/ on the same jplayer but i want any one to help me with the code as i want jplayer to stop playing from database automaticaly when shoutcast starts streaming and when streaming is off it should again start playing form the database.
2nd thing is that the jplayer randomly selects the song for every listener so its kind of unusual for a radio as radio plays one song at a time for all listeners so i want to know is their any way that jplayer randomly select a song from database and play it for all listeners and repeat the same procedure.

Comment: You want to make it play the same song but a random song for all users? You can do it when the first song is started, maybe put it in the database and get it back for all other users... But i don't think it's the right way to create an online radio

Answer (score 0):

If you want a traditional internet radio service (all users hearing the same thing at the same time) you should encode a stream server-side.  Clients then connect to the server which sends them the stream data as it is being encoded.

Typically, you will use [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools/)/[Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) for this.  For encoding, you can use a variety of software.  I personally use [Edcast](http://code.google.com/p/edcast-reborn/downloads/list).  For audio playback, I typically use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc).